# Blackberry 10 Alpha simulator on stuck on MacBook

Tags: simulator, alpha, blackberry-10

I try to run BB10 Alpha Simulator and it stop at 
`starting service: screen`.
I wait about 1 hour, but nothing happened.
If I try to run it in Safe Mode it works, but is really really slow!

Please help!

Comment: What OS are you on? What version of VM Player/Fusion? Are you running the Gold SDK simulator?

Answer (score 0):

I rum MAC OS X 10.7.5, VMware 5.0.2, and I run GOLD SDK Simulator. But I think I found the answer. My graphic's card performance are realy low. It start in safe mode because video acceleration is disabled!

Answer (score 0):

The performance of BB 10 simulator really depends on your system graphics card. But once if the simulator starts never do power off the virtual machine always do suspend for quick start the simulator